# Move Folder option missing from Site Collection Admin

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, administration, folder, move

I need to move several folders to another location in SharePoint 2010. However, the "Move Folders" option is missing. I have checked the settings with other sites, but I cant find any difference in the setting.

Only this particular site is missing the option. Seek your kind assistance to solve this issue.

[image: this is with the Move Folders option]

Comment: Hi, did you do any other settings before this? Have you tried using another account with admin privileges?